# PathLocationStrategy and webpack-dev historyApiFallback rewrites

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have something working but I have no idea why, and I would like to know why !

My app is in Angular 5 with webpack-dev-server 2.9.5.

I was at first using HashLocationStrategy for my routing, but when I tried to implement OpenId connect, it appeared that I had to change.

OpenID needed a redirectURL at the end of the url, so I was supposed to have something like that : `https://openid.com/redirectUrl=https://localhost:9446/#/openid`.

But unfortunatly for me, it didn't work so well considering it was skipping everything after the #, redirecting me to `https://localhost:9446/` instead of `https://localhost:9446/#/openid`.

Therefor I had to change to a PathLocationStrategy, so that I could have`https://openid.com/redirectUrl=https://localhost:9446/openid`.
Now my problem was, OpenID is correctly redirecting me at the right location, but my app doesn't want to route my component. (which was working before)

```
export const OPENLOGIN_ROUTE: Route = {
path: 'openid',
component: OpenidComponent
```

};
Instead of loading the page, I have "Cannot GET /openid" in the top left of my screen .

I figured out a solution, by adding in my webpack.dev :

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        rewrites: [
            {from: /openid/, to: '/#/openid'},
        ]
    },
```

It's working great, but I don't know **why**..

How is redirecting /openid to /#/openid solving my problem ?

I hope it is understandable, thanks for your help.